# Слежение за очередью печати

Tags: java

Не прошу писать за меня код, а только указать в нужном направлении.

Есть действие: Пользователь отправляет файл на печать.

Необходимо: На сервере печати запустить приложение, которое посмотрит в заданиях печати -

1. имя пользователя
2. отправленный файл
3. статус "Напечатано" или "В ожидании" (Файлы после печати из пула не удаляются).

Ну и естественно, если файл "print.pdf" имеет статус "Напечатано", отправить эту информацию на собственный сервер (POST-запрос) для ведения статистики напечатанных файлов.

Прошу подсказать, какие библиотеки можно использовать, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `PrintServiceLookup`